# Lost write access to USB 3.0 thumb drive

Tags: usb, permissions

[image]

[image]

I left it overnight plugged into the dock of my lenovo. The other day it was quite hot.

I could no longer write to it even if seemingly I have permission as the screenshots above indicate.

How to make sure if it's dead and if it's not how to fix it?

edit: formatting didn't help

edit2: FSCK didn't help

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for user: 
fsck from util-linux 2.29
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
/dev/sdb1: clean, 11/3915776 files, 324663/15663096 blocks
```

Comment: Not to sound corny, but I suggest to shutdown your Lenovo, remove the USB and let it cool down. Remove the Lenovo from the dock, start it. Plugin the USB in the Lenovo, so we know it is not the same USB port. Check if you can write files now. If you cannot, well... you will have to buy a new USB drive and a fan to cool it if you let it in the dock overnight again.

Comment: You find more tips at the following link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297